# My series is not printing the correct sum. What can i do?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int number1,number2,i,j,sum=0,c=0;

  cin>>number1;
  cin>>number2;

  for(i=number1;i<=number2;i++)
  {

        for(j=1;j<=number1;j++)
        {
            sum=sum+j;

        }
        cout<<sum<<endl;

    }
```

It should be printing the sum of series like 1,12,123,1234. If user gives input 3 and 4 then it should be printing the sum (1+2+3)=6 and (1+2+3+4)=10.

Comment: What is your input and output?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to tell, It should be printing the sum of series like 1,12,123,1234. If user gives input 3 and 4 then it should be printing the sum (1+2+3)=6 and (1+2+3+4)=10. thank you

Comment: @SadiaDia update your question instead of posting comments.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my post

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies It should be printing the sum of series like 1,12,123,1234. If user gives input 3 and 4 then it should be printing the sum (1+2+3)=6 and (1+2+3+4)=10.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Thank you, Actually i am a beginner. I need to learn a lot more things. I appreciate your help.  @NathanOliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need more attention.

```
  for(i=number1;i<=number2;i++)
  {
        sum = 0 // you forgot this
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++) // this was wrong to
        {
            sum=sum+j;

        }
        cout<<sum<<endl;

    }
```

Comment: @SadiaDia You should accept one of the answers, http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is  in this for loop

```
for(i=number1;i<=number2;i++)
{ 
    sum = 0; // You must make sum = 0 here
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        sum=sum+j;

    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;

}
```

Edit:
Better use this:

```
for(int i=number1;i<=number2;i++)
    sum  = (i * (i+1))/2;
```

Comment: I have already tried this, It is still giving wrong output, this time it is giving the same output again and again :(